# How to Enable annotation processing android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1?

Tags: android-studio

I can't find the following setting:

```
Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors -> 
Enable annotation processing.
```

It seems that it has changed in android studio arctic fox 2020.3.1 patch 3